# php class not saving variable

Tags: php, arrays, json, class

I have a simple API class that talks with its web-based counterpart.
All works fine, just one variable denies to be saved.

I have a variable called $scope, initialised at the top of the class:

```
class Api {

    private $scope;

    public function set_scope( $s ) {
        $this->scope = serialize($s);
        return true;
    }

    private function get_scope() {
        return unserialize($this->scope);
    }

}
```

Next I'm getting the scope via API from the web script as JSON, I json_decode it as an array (second parameter as true) and in that form, I pass it through set_scope() function.

I am 10000000% sure API returns JSON, when var_dump'ed it returns me a proper array data.

For some reason though, that data is not saved into the $scope variable.

Any ideas?

**Edit #1:**

I call function `get_scope` within the class, in another function. I was trying to set that variable directly, so just using `$this->scope=$scope`, without success though. I use the same structured functions to save/get other variables, and all of them are working, except this one.

Other function looks like that:

```
public function get_modules() {

    $av_modules = $this->available_modules;
    $scope = $this->get_scope();

    var_dump($scope);

    foreach($scope as $mod) {
        $av_modules[$mod] = true;
    }

    return $av_modules;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm wondering why you `serialize` the value when you set it, and `unserialize` when getting it. Isn't that rather superfluous?

Comment: I'm trying various ways to save it, but even using `$this->scope` does not save the value, and I have no idea why

Answer (score 1):

The `get_scope` method is private (thus cannot be called from outside itself).

Make the `get_scope` method public and the value will be returned.

Comment: I call that function `get_scope` within the class, in another function. I was trying to set that variable directly, so just using `$this->scope=$scope`, without success though. I use the same structured functions to save/get other variables, and all of them are working, except this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your **get_scope()** function is declare as private. To use it outside class, you should change it to public.